# Alias template with container's iterators on Visual Studio

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, alias

Next block of code compiles pretty successfully:

```
#include <map>

template<typename KEY>
using umap = std::map<KEY, std::wstring>;

int main()
{
  umap<int> m;
  umap<double> m2;
}
```

Meanwhile, adding an *iterator* template the same way as the map makes the compiler swear and complain about **error C2061: syntax error**. So the next block won't compile:

```
template<typename KEY>
using umap = std::map<KEY, std::wstring>;

template<typename KEY>
using iter = std::map<KEY, std::wstring>::iterator;

int main()
{
  umap<int> m;
  umap<double> m2;
}
```

Can't we using alias declarations with iterators? Why? And would be a workaround?

Comment: `using iter = typename std::map<KEY, std::wstring>::iterator;`

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `typename` keyword before `std::map<KEY, std::wstring>::iterator`, because it is a dependent scope.

Thus, your second code should be:

```
template<typename KEY>
using umap = std::map<KEY, std::wstring>;

template<typename KEY>
using iter = typename std::map<KEY, std::wstring>::iterator;

int main()
{
  umap<int> m;
  umap<double> m2;
}
```

Comment: splendida. grazie